# Copying data from one dgv to another dgv with values and count using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to have contents from one dgv populate in another dgv.  To make matters more complicated, I would like to have them listed with the contents and then the quantities of each occurrence. For example.

DGV1

Reese's|Snickers|Twix

Reese's|Snickers|3 Musketeers

*empty*|Mars|*empty*

DGV2

Reese's|2

Snickers|2

Twix|1

3 Musketeers|1

Mars|1

This is my first post and I'm honestly very new to C#.  Any help you can provide would be great.  Lastly, There is a list of items available for selection with dgv1 so trying to write the code to search for specific values would be impractical.

Comment: Your title is missing a verb. So: Do you just want to show the same data or do you want to create (independent) copies?

Comment: I would like it to be the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you're looking to do an unpivot operation.

- Create a DataTable and bind it to your first grid:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();      //create a new datatable
    dt.Columns.Add("Bar1");              //add columns for the bars
    dt.Columns.Add("Bar2");
    dt.Columns.Add("Bar3");
    _barsDataGridView.DataSource = dt;   //bind the grid to it
```

- Let the user fill in some stuff
- When the user clicks a button, scan each row of the table, and track the entries into a Dictionary that keeps count, then put the dictionary contents to another datatable bound to another grid:

```
    _barsDataGridView.EndEdit();                        //finish any current edits
    var dt = _barsDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable; //get the source datatable from the grid

    var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();  //create a dictionary to map bar names to counts
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows){          //loop over the data
      foreach(object o in r.ItemArray){     //pull the row data as an object array, loop over it
        string bar = o as string;           //turn the field back into a string (items in the itemarray always look like objects)   

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(bar))       //if there is nothing there
          continue;                         //skip

        if(!d.ContainsKey(bar))             //if we never saw this bar before
          d[bar] = 0;                       //make a dictionary entry for it

        d[bar]++;                           //count the bar
      }
    }

    DataTable dtUnpivot = new DataTable();  //make a new datatable to hold our results
    dtUnpivot.Columns.Add("Name");
    dtUnpivot.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
    foreach(var kvp in d){                       //iterate over the dictionary
      dtUnpivot.Rows.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);    //populating the dt; key is bar name, value is count
    }
    _unpivotDataGridView.DataSource = dtUnpivot; //show the dt in the grid
```

I didn't take the LINQ approach because youre learning; get your head round this first - there's probably enough going on :)

Edit:

Getting the grid to run the other way

```
DataTable dtUnpivot = new DataTable();  //make a new datatable to hold our results
    dtUnpivot.Columns.Add("X"); //need one column 
    dtUnpivot.Rows.Add("X");
    foreach(var kvp in d){                       //iterate over the dictionary
      
      var col = dtUnpivot.Columns.Add(kvp.Key, typeof(int));   //add a new column 
      dtUnpivot.Rows[0][col] = kvp.Value //store value in the first row new col 
    }
    _unpivotDataGridView.DataSource = dtUnpivot; //show the dt in the grid
```

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant but where exactly do I put the code regarding the data table?

Comment: The top one in the form load perhaps, the bottom one in a button click handler perhaps

Comment: Using the generic type 'KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>' requires 2 type arguments is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Make the line either `foreach(var kvp in d)` or `foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in d)` - typo, sorry

Comment: Caius I can't thank you enough.  Its working with one small exception, if any of the cells are empty its giving me the following error:  System.InvalidCastException:  'Unable to cast object of type'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.'  It's showing the error on the string bar = (string)o; portion of the button click handler code

Comment: Change the line to say `string bar = o as string;` - it will do the cast in a different way, one that doesn't error out if it fails

Comment: Caius = "Hero";

Comment: Thank you! been a pleasure (and sorry I didn't get these minor bugs right first time)

Comment: So I have a dgv that has predetermined selections the user can pick from and when using this code it's not populating the values outside of the columns listed in the form load.  What can I do to make the columns I've already created post values in the dgv2?

Comment: I don't know; you have never shown the code for how you make that grid.. Probably you should use DataGridViewComboBoxColumns with item lists binded to the lists of chocolate bars

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697591/minimizing-column-range-of-dictionary-in-data-tables)

Comment: Is there a way to change the foreach from Rows to Columns?  I’m needing to limit the range of columns theDictionary builds from.

Comment: Yes, just change the last code so that it creates new columns rather than new rows

Comment: I'm in reference to `var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)`.  How can I limit the column range it reads from?  For example, if I only want it to read column 2 and 3 and ignore column 1

Comment: `foreach(object o in r.ItemArray){` reads the columns. Either swap it out for a `for(int i=1;i<r.ItemArray.Length;i++)` (most flexible) or skip one item (i.e. the first) with `foreach(object o in r.ItemArray.Skip(1)){`